# Exsheets does not work with unicode-math package

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, exsheets

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xfrac,fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=lm]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[version=cambria]{Cambria Math}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\begin{document}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\mathversion{lm}
\section*{Latin Modern}
There follows a question
\begin{question}
This is the first question
\end{question}\\
\begin{question}[name=Problem]
This is the second question
\end{question}


\setmainfont{Cambria}
\mathversion{cambria}
\section*{Cambria, Cambria Math}
There follows a question 
\begin{question}
This is the first question
\end{question}\\
\begin{question}[name=Problem]
This is the second question
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image]

Does anybody has a solution?

*Exsheets works fine with xelatex if unicode-math is not in the preamble

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issue/5/exsheets-doesnt-play-nice-with-lualatex

Comment: Thnx, it works fine, but only with \NewQuSolPair{exercise}{answer} .
The command \RenewQuSolPair{question}{solution} does not do anything.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\RenewQuSolPair{question}{solution}}` (in the preamble) works for me. By the way: the `\\` after `\end{question}` is wrong...

Comment: This should read: »the ``\\`` after `\end{question}`«

Comment: Can you post your preamble?

Comment: I know, i put \\ after \end{question} to see if the question environment worked as a text. (Before your solution)

Comment: I simply took your example, removed the font settings, added the `\AtBeginDocument` line, and compiled

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known issue](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issue/5/exsheets-doesnt-play-nice-with-lualatex). The file `unicode-math-table.tex` that is loaded by `unicode-math` contains the following line:

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"0003F}{\question}{\mathord}{question mark}%
```

This means that at begin document `\question` gets defined or redefined (`unicode-math` does `\AtBeginDocument{\um_define_math_chars:}` which supposedly initiates the definition...) The file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\show\question
\begin{document}
\show\question
\end{document}
```

produces in the log

```
> \question=undefined.
l.3 \show\question
```

and

```
> \question=the character ?.
l.5 \show\question
```

And the character `?` is exactly what you're seeing when you use `exsheets`' `\begin{question}`. (Remember that `\begin{foo}` amongst other things calls the command `\foo`.)

There are two solutions for this:

1. redefine `\question` again at begin document by adding

   ```
   \AtBeginDocument{\RenewQuSolPair{question}{solution}}
   ```

   after loading both `unicode-math` and `exsheets`.  You'll lose `unicode-math`'s `\question` then.
2. Use another exercise environment by defining a new one, e.g.,

   ```
   \NewQuSolPair{exercise}{answer}
   ```

Here's an example for the first version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewQuSolPair{question}{solution}}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
  This is a question.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}[print]
  This is a solution.
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Here's an example for the second possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\NewQuSolPair{exercise}{answer}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
  This is a question.
\end{exercise}
\begin{answer}[print]
  This is a solution.
\end{answer}
\end{document}
```

Both give

[image]

Comment: Yes, because i want to use unicode-math and exsheets together. Thnx again