# Why is unicode-math not working with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, unicode-math, braces

This thread evoked from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/161528/revisions).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math} % This causes the question mark bug
% This code requises unicode-math
% How can you use the code without unicode-math -package?
\setmathfont[BoldFont={latinmodern-math.otf}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana-Math.otf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand\MyText[4][0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace},decorate,thick]
   ( $ ({pic cs:#3}|-{pic cs:#2}) + (#1,1.3ex) $ ) --  
    node[anchor=west,xshift=5pt,text width=5cm] {#4} 
  ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (#1,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

% I have defined question like this
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Lorem ipsum?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

I am thinking why you need the [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package for the TikZ code.

Why does the TikZ code require `unicode-math` package?

Comment: The question mark has nothing to do with tikz (and tikz doesn't require unicode-math). unicode-math defines a `\question` command and this clash with the name of your environment. Use a different name.

Comment: @Ulrike The problem is not in the question command, I think. There was mistake in the example code here. I had commented those lines out in my code.

Comment: @Masi You can't, of course, use the `question` environment without defining it, because there's no predefined one; so this code is wrong in the first place. Without `unicode-math` it wouldn't compile; with `unicode-math` it's using the `\question` command that is completely unsuitable for this usage.

Comment: That's the same problem as here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146516/5049 just as @Ulrike said

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a very unfortunate state of affairs.

The problem is that `unicode-math` does most of its work during processing of `\AtBeginDocument` tokens, that is, when `\begin{document}` is scanned. Part of this is to define `\question` as a math symbol producing a question mark.

So, when you define the `question` environment with `\newtheorem`, no error is raised. But afterwards `unicode-math` redefines `\question` (which is the macro executed when `\begin{question}` is processed.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math} % This causes the question mark bug

\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Lorem ipsum?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

You can either change the environment's name, or restore the definition; the second strategy can be implemented with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math} % This causes the question mark bug

\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\let\masiquestion\question
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\umquestion\question
  \let\question\masiquestion
}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Lorem ipsum?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

In my opinion, `unicode-math` ***ought to*** issue at least a warning when redefining a command.

Comment: Hmm, issuing warnings would be a problem since it shares 100s of symbols with LaTeX and amssymb. (I could omit the warning for the standard names, I guess.) But there are a few symbols in the lower slots that shouldn't be taking such generic names; I'll update them shortly.

Answer (score 15):

As I already wrote in the comments: unicode-math defines `\question`. So you can't use "question" as the name of your environment. Replace it by e.g. questionX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math} % This causes the question mark bug

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}
\newtheorem{questionX}[theorem]{Question}


\begin{document}
\question \question \question %defined by unicode math.


\begin{question} %fails
Lorem ipsum?
\end{question}

\begin{questionX} %works
Lorem ipsum?
\end{questionX}
\end{document}
```