# What does this error mean in Mathtools-colon?

Tags: xetex, errors, warnings, mac, mathtools

I have not been able to produce the minimal example, but I get this error

```
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
*
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 128.
*************************************************
* unicode-math warning: "mathtools-colon"
* 
* I'm going to overwrite the following commands from the `mathtools' package:
* 
*     \dblcolon, \coloneqq, \Coloneqq, \eqqcolon.
* 
* Note that since I won't overwrite the other colon-like commands, using them
* will lead to inconsistencies.
*************************************************

./summary_patology.tex:168: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.168 \begin{document}

./summary_patology.tex:168: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.168 \begin{document}

./summary_patology.tex:168: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.168 \begin{document}

./summary_patology.tex:168: Undefined control sequence.
\Hy@temp ...unrestored@protected@xdef \@thefnmark 
                                                  {\ref {#1}}\endgroup \@foo...
l.168 \begin{document}

./summary_patology.tex:168: Use of \@BOOKMARK doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.168 \begin{document}

./summary_patology.tex:168: Use of \@BOOKMARK doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def \reserved@a *
                             {\@refstar }\reserved@a 
l.168 \begin{document}

./summary_patology.tex:168: Argument of \@refstar has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.168 \begin{document}

Runaway argument?
./summary_patology.tex:168: Paragraph ended before \@refstar was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.168 \begin{document}


(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
No pages of output.
```

Some packages of mine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% \usepackage{background}
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp, mathtools, xparse}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/masi/Dropbox/Patology_and_Biopsy/images/} }
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m F}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{Tabbing}
\usepackage{doi, natbib}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
allcolors=blue
}
\usepackage{enumerate} % alpha numerical ordering
\usepackage{titling} % Two titles in one document
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % underline by \uline{lorem}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % To have chemical symbols like \ce{O2^{.-}}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} % rowcolor for tables
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{colori}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colorii}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\NewDocumentCommand\MyArrow{O{0pt}mmmO{out=150,in=210}}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw [->,thick,line width=4pt,#4]
    ( $ ({pic cs:#3}|-{pic cs:#2}) + (-#1,1.3ex) $ ) to[#5]  
    ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (-#1,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Question and Answer %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
%   font = \normalfont,
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

% Unicode-math bug fix
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161809/why-is-unicode-math-not-working-with-tikz
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\let\masiquestion\question
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\umquestion\question
  \let\question\masiquestion
}


\newtheorem{answer_original}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  font = \normalfont,
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer_original}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@my@box}
\newenvironment{answer}%
{%
    \noindent
    \begin{lrbox}{\@my@box}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{answer_original}
}%
{%
    \end{answer_original}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \rotatebox{0}{\usebox{\@my@box}}
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Smaller things

\newtheorem{sidenote}{Sidenote}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{sidenote}


\newtheorem{case}{Case logic}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{case}

\newtheorem{citation}{Citation}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{citation}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BRACES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setmathfont[BoldFont={latinmodern-math.otf}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana-Math.otf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand\MyText[4][0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace},decorate,thick]
   ( $ ({pic cs:#3}|-{pic cs:#2}) + (#1,1.3ex) $ ) --  
    node[anchor=west,xshift=5pt,text width=5cm] {#4} 
  ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (#1,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Counter Section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
  \def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
    \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \LARGE \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\@addtoreset{section}{part}    
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%
%

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}] \emph}{\end{trivlist}}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{Keywords:} #1}




\begin{document} % The error refers here!

\title{Introduction to General Pathology Notes} 

Lorem
\end{document}
```

There seems to some problem with braces but I cannot see any alone brace. 
I think the problem is probably with unicode-math, but I do not understand why.

**What may cause this problem?**

Comment: You should know better by now... Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It's a warning not an error. `unicode-math` redefines a lot of stuff related to math, it just tells you what it does.

Comment: The listed symbols are built by `mathtools`, but are available as symbols on their own with `unicode-math`, which thus redefines them. It's nothing you should worry about.

Comment: You can avoid the [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) *warnings* by loading it in the following way: `\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}`.

Comment: I added the error messages which I have. They seem to suggest me about some brace missing, but this is not the case, since I have  removed nearly everything in the code. This seems to be a problem with interpreter probably, since it just suddenly come. I need to run the code on other machine.

Comment: Can you show line 168 in `summary_patology.tex`?

Comment: @egrep I added the beginning of my code. The line 168 refers to the line **\begin{document}**.

Comment: I don't see how you can have a problem and not be abel to make a MWE showing it. (As a last solution, you can give an entire document as an example.)

Comment: I get two errors, but not the one you mention. The first occurs because you have `\newtheorem{question}{Question}` twice, so the second throws an error. The second error occurs for `\newtheorem{citation}{Citation}` because a `\citation` command is already defined. Changing this to e.g. `\newtheorem{mcitation}{Citation}` and removing the second `\newtheorem{question}{Question}` there are no errors, only the warnings from `unicode-math`.

Comment: I did those two changes. I still get the similar error as before: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-03%20at%2015.20.31.png The problem can be in the compiler or something else that went broken for some reason.

Comment: I get exactly the same as @TorbjørnT. Removing l. 60 and changing `citation` in l. 111 results in the comment `*************************************************
* unicode-math warning: "mathtools-overbracket"
* 
* Using \overbracket and \underbracke from mathtools package.
* 
* Use \Uoverbracket and \Uunderbracke for original unicode-math definition.
*************************************************` for me.

Comment: **Which typesetting engine do you use?** I get those errors with XeLaTeX. Other engines do not compile. LuaTeX engine my TexPad does not have.

Comment: XeLaTeX for me.

Comment: `unicode-math` requires `xelatex` or `lualatex`, so naturally one of those. Same result for both, with a recently updated TeX Live 2013. Are you able to reduce your example to the minimum showing the problem?

Comment: I suggest to make a completely fresh install of your LaTeX distribution (and then switch to TeX Live if it isn't the one you are already using).

Comment: MacTex 2013 is the one which I am using: http://tug.org/mactex/ MacTex install completely unmodified TeX live 2014. I will install the program again.

Comment: A'ha! So you are an Apple minion. `:(` Then MacTeX is the way to go. Try to reinstall it.

Comment: Got it running, it fails due to the unicode-math pkg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not compile because of the line 11, uncomment `%\usepackage{unicode-math}` and uncomment

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BRACES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setmathfont[BoldFont={latinmodern-math.otf}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana-Math.otf}
```

where I don't know anything about the package. Perhaps someone here able to help with it you?

**Code Compiling with OSX Texpad 1.4.7 -- this should be the newest so the same as yours**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% \usepackage{background}
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp, mathtools, xparse}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/masi/Dropbox/Patology_and_Biopsy/images/} }
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m F}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{Tabbing}
\usepackage{doi, natbib}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
allcolors=blue
}
\usepackage{enumerate} % alpha numerical ordering
\usepackage{titling} % Two titles in one document
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % underline by \uline{lorem}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % To have chemical symbols like \ce{O2^{.-}}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} % rowcolor for tables
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{colori}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colorii}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\NewDocumentCommand\MyArrow{O{0pt}mmmO{out=150,in=210}}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw [->,thick,line width=4pt,#4]
    ( $ ({pic cs:#3}|-{pic cs:#2}) + (-#1,1.3ex) $ ) to[#5]  
    ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (-#1,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Question and Answer %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
%   font = \normalfont,
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

% Unicode-math bug fix
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161809/why-is-unicode-math-not-working-with-tikz
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\let\masiquestion\question
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\umquestion\question
  \let\question\masiquestion
}


\newtheorem{answer_original}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  font = \normalfont,
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer_original}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@my@box}
\newenvironment{answer}%
{%
    \noindent
    \begin{lrbox}{\@my@box}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{answer_original}
}%
{%
    \end{answer_original}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \rotatebox{0}{\usebox{\@my@box}}
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Smaller things

\newtheorem{sidenote}{Sidenote}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{sidenote}


\newtheorem{case}{Case logic}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{case}

\newtheorem{citation}{Citation}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{citation}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BRACES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setmathfont[BoldFont={latinmodern-math.otf}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana-Math.otf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand\MyText[4][0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace},decorate,thick]
   ( $ ({pic cs:#3}|-{pic cs:#2}) + (#1,1.3ex) $ ) --  
    node[anchor=west,xshift=5pt,text width=5cm] {#4} 
  ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (#1,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Counter Section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
  \def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
    \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \LARGE \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\@addtoreset{section}{part}    
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%
%

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}] \emph}{\end{trivlist}}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{Keywords:} #1}




\begin{document} % The error refers here!

\title{Introduction to General Pathology Notes} 

Lorem
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer; Masi would obviously like to use `unicode-math`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I like to use Unicode-math, but now, it is most important to get the thing compile because I am in short time now. I have no idea what is wrong with Unicode-math in OSX. I think it is OSX related issue, since the thing compiles fine on Linux.

Comment: I am open to other answers, but this will be the way how I work now without unicode-math because of its instabilities in OSX.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but this answer might be helpful to someone:

To answer the question in the title, your error, 'unicode-math warning: "mathtools-colon"', is simply due to mathtools and unicode-math trying to use the same names for things.  It's just a warning from unicode-math as the packages aren't 100% compatible, but can be ignored. You can suppress it if you wish with the option:

```
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon}]{unicode-math}
```

So there's that. On the other errors you have, there appears to be some issue with hyperref, but I don't see any problem with your loading of the package so I'm guessing it's still a compatibility issue with unicode-math and other packages, so to fix those:

Firstly you should load mathtools after unicode-math as loading them the other way round has been known to cause issues in some cases.

Next, you're also mixing pdflatex and xelatex/lualatex packages. Since you wish to use unicode-math, you must be using xelatex or lualatex (if not, here's one reason it won't compile). Assuming this, then you shouldn't be using fontenc, but fontspec.

Next, amsmath is invoked by mathtools and so is unnecessary, and amsfonts is redundant if using unicode-math, as is amssymb; at best these packages are no longer required as the functionality they add in pdflatex can now be achieved through other, better means, but they're also unlikely to play nicely together.

Finally, any other issues I'd check the other packages to make sure they're all compatible with your chosen engine and each other, and also try changing the load order of any packages that are throwing up errors (like hyperref). Failing that, update your packages, and do a fresh compile after deleting all auxiliary files. More often than not this will fix such issues.

Comment: My version (`v0.8o`) of `unicode-math` seems to not give warnings with their labels to be used with `warnings-off={...}`: E.g., `Package unicode-math Warning: I'm going to overwrite the following commands...`