# How do I fix incompatibility of exercise and unicode-math packages?

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode-math, exercises

I wanted to use the exercise package in a LaTeX-document that is processed with LuaLaTeX. In this case, I encountered the problem that numbering and formatting of questions does not work correctly.

How can I use both package, i.e. how do I debug and fix such an incompatibility?

I reduced this problem to a MWE which is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% Incompatible with exercise package
\usepackage{fontspec}% I want to select a different font

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}% this requires unicode-math

\begin{document}

\chapter{List of problems}
\begin{ExerciseList}
    \Exercise Prove Bernoulli's inequality
    \[
        (1+x)^n \geq 1+nx, \text{ for } x\geq -1 \text{ and } n\geq 0.
    \]
    \Exercise Find out if the following equations are true.
        \Question $(1 + 5)^2 \geq 11$
        \Question $1 < 5$
        \Question $1 > 5$
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

Processing this with `lualatex` (or `xelatex` -- both using the `-8bit` option) yields a document where the questions are not numbered correctly.

Omitting the `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and the `\setmathfont{...}` (which requires `unicode-math`), then the output is as expected.

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146516/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unicode-math` package defines `\Question` as a math symbol, precisely U+2047 DOUBLE QUESTION MARK, that is, ⁇.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}% this requires unicode-math

\let\exerciseQuestion\Question
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mathQuestion\Question
  \let\Question\exerciseQuestion
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{List of problems}
\begin{ExerciseList}
    \Exercise Prove Bernoulli's inequality
    \[
        (1+x)^n \geq 1+nx, \text{ for } x\geq -1 \text{ and } n\geq 0.
    \]
    \Exercise Find out if the following equations are true.
        \Question $(1 + 5)^2 \geq 11$
        \Question $1 < 5$
        \Question $1 > 5$
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, it works fine. Actually, I already had the suspicion that the `\Question` caused the conflict, but I was not sure and more particularly, I did not understand how to solve this. Is your proposal a typical "idiom" for resolving a name clash of two packages?

Comment: *for future readers* Not sure about the idiom part, but you can write such code yourself if you understand how it works. Lookup documentation of `\AtBeginDocument` and `\let`.